# How to delegate listening to entering states of a `transitions` state machine?

Tags: python, events, transition, state-machine, pytransitions

I am trying to use the [transitions](https://pypi.org/project/transitions/) library.
This question follows [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68176471/how-to-pass-parameters-to-on-enter-callbacks-in-transitions-library/68201420?noredirect=1#comment120625970_68201420), quite loosely.

I would like to delegate listening to `on_enter` events to all states and create several such listeners that can subscribe and be notified when entering a state.
In my case, I want to notify an external event system to subscribe to a different configuration of events depending on the state.

---

For this example I will use a state machine (say solid<->fluid<->gas with events [heat, cool]).

This can be done quite easily using the library like so

```
from transitions import Machine
from transitions import EventData


class Matter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        transitions = [
            {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': 'solid', 'dest': 'liquid'},
            {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': 'liquid', 'dest': 'gas'},
            {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': 'gas', 'dest': 'liquid'},
            {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': 'liquid', 'dest': 'solid'}
        ]
        self.machine = Machine(
                model=self,
                states=['solid', 'liquid', 'gas'],
                transitions=transitions,
                initial='solid',
                send_event=True
        )

    def on_enter_gas(self, event: EventData):
        print(f"entering gas from {event.transition.source}")

    def on_enter_liquid(self, event: EventData):
        print(f"entering liquid from {event.transition.source}")

    def on_enter_solid(self, event: EventData):
        print(f"entering solid from {event.transition.source}")


matter = Matter()
matter.heat()  # entering liquid from solid
matter.heat()  # entering gas from liquid
matter.cool()  # entering liquid from gas
matter.cool()  # entering solid from liquid
```

---

Great! Now, I want to notify *externally, via subscriptions* about `on_enter` events.
I want to do that in a way that would least couple the outside world to the insides of the machine, so that if I were to change a state name, or add or remove a state, I wouldn't worry about breaking any users of the machine.

One way I could accomplish that would be the following, with drawbacks of being coupled to the insides of the machine, and forcing me to implement a lot of the functionality of the library myself.

```
from transitions import Machine
from transitions import EventData
from typing import Callable


class Matter(object):
    states = ['solid', 'liquid', 'gas']
    
    def __init__(self):
        transitions = [
            {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': 'solid', 'dest': 'liquid'},
            {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': 'liquid', 'dest': 'gas'},
            {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': 'gas', 'dest': 'liquid'},
            {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': 'liquid', 'dest': 'solid'}
        ]
        self.machine = Machine(
                model=self,
                states=self.states,
                transitions=transitions,
                initial='solid',
                send_event=True
        )

        self._subscriptions = {}

    def on_enter_gas(self, event: EventData):
        print(f"entering gas from {event.transition.source}")
        if "on_enter_gas" in self._subscriptions:
            self._subscriptions["on_enter_solid"]()

    def on_enter_liquid(self, event: EventData):
        print(f"entering liquid from {event.transition.source}")
        if "on_enter_liquid" in self._subscriptions:
            self._subscriptions["on_enter_solid"]()

    def on_enter_solid(self, event: EventData):
        print(f"entering solid from {event.transition.source}")
        if "on_enter_solid" in self._subscriptions:
            self._subscriptions["on_enter_solid"]()
        
    def subscribe(self, state: str, trigger: str, callback: Callable):
        assert state in self.states
        machine_event = trigger + "_" + state
        if machine_event not in self._subscriptions:
            self._subscriptions[machine_event] = callback
```

This allows to add *external* callbacks for any state.

According to a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68176471/how-to-pass-parameters-to-on-enter-callbacks-in-transitions-library), the above should have some better API to dynamically add subscriptions per state, but I was not able to find it in [the doc](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions#callbacks).

---

Even if this is indeed possible with the library, I believe that is not enough.
Any subscriber would have to know the states of the machine in order to subscribe to <on_enter>them, instead of simply being a listener on the machine, and implementing just any event to be notified it occured, just like one can easily add a `on_enter_solid` just through the existance of a state "solid".

What I would ideally like to do is have some listener class I can inherit (or otherwise) and only implement the methods I need to listen to, *externally*.

**What is the best way to accomplish this, or similar using the library?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to notify externally, via subscriptions about on_enter events.
> I want to do that in a way that would least couple the outside world to the insides of the machine, so that if I were to change a state name, or add or remove a state, I wouldn't worry about breaking any users of the machine.

The least coupling would be to just forward the event and let the subscriber decide what to do with it:

```
from transitions import Machine
from transitions import EventData
from typing import Callable


class Observer:

    def state_changed(self, event_data: EventData):
        print(f"state is now '{event_data.state.name}'")


class SubscribableMachine(Machine):
    states = ['solid', 'liquid', 'gas']
    transitions = [
        {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': 'solid', 'dest': 'liquid'},
        {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': 'liquid', 'dest': 'gas'},
        {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': 'gas', 'dest': 'liquid'},
        {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': 'liquid', 'dest': 'solid'}
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(states=self.states, transitions=self.transitions,
                         initial='solid', after_state_change="notify",
                         send_event=True)
        self._subscriptions = []

    def notify(self, event_data: EventData):
        for func in self._subscriptions:
            func(event_data)

    def subscribe(self, func: Callable):
        self._subscriptions.append(func)


machine = SubscribableMachine()
observer = Observer()
machine.subscribe(observer.state_changed)
machine.heat()  # >>> state is now 'LIQUID'
```

If you let observer subscribe to particular transition and/or state events this would obviously break their code when you rename these events later on. However, in my opinion, just passing events drastically reduces the usefulness of a state machine and the state pattern in general since it's one of the best parts of the state pattern that it gets rid of if-elif-else-cascades.

> What I would ideally like to do is have some listener class I can inherit (or otherwise) and only implement the methods I need to listen to, externally.

I'd say you don't need a particular listener class. You can add callables to the state enter/exit callbacks directly. Furthermore, you can replace strings with (string) Enums as state identifier. This way, you could change the Enum's value without any influence on the observers. This prevents typos when subscribing to a particular state:

```py
from transitions import Machine
from transitions import EventData
from typing import Callable
from enum import Enum, auto


class Observer:

    def state_changed(self, event_data: EventData):
        print(f"state is now '{event_data.state.name}'")


class State(Enum):
    SOLID = auto()
    LIQUID = auto()
    GAS = auto()


class SubscribableMachine(Machine):

    transitions = [
        {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': State.SOLID, 'dest': State.LIQUID},
        {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': State.LIQUID, 'dest': State.GAS},
        {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': State.GAS, 'dest': State.LIQUID},
        {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': State.LIQUID, 'dest': State.SOLID}
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(states=State, transitions=self.transitions,
                         initial=State.SOLID, send_event=True)

    def subscribe(self, func: Callable, state: State):
        self.get_state(state).on_enter.append(func)

    def unsubscribe(self, func: Callable, state: State):
        self.get_state(state).on_enter.remove(func)


machine = SubscribableMachine()
observer = Observer()
machine.subscribe(observer.state_changed, State.LIQUID)
machine.heat()  # >>> state is now 'LIQUID'
machine.heat()
assert machine.state == State.GAS
machine.unsubscribe(observer.state_changed, State.LIQUID)
machine.cool()  # no output
assert machine.state == State.LIQUID
```

> What is the syntax to subscribe in the same way to specific transitions?

For transitions, you can use `machine.get_transitions(trigger, source, dest)` to get a set of transitions. As mentions in the documentation (for instance [Callback execution order](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions#callback-execution-order)), transitions feature two callback events: `before` and `after`. If you want to be informed after a transition has taken place (also after `State.enter` has been called), your subscribe/unsubscribe methods could look like this:

```
    def subscribe(self, func, trigger="", source="*", dest="*"):
        for transition in self.get_transitions(trigger, source, dest):
            transition.after.append(func)
            
    def unsubscribe(self, func, trigger="", source="*", dest="*"):
        for transition in self.get_transitions(trigger, source, dest):
            transition.after.remove(func)
# ...
machine.subscribe(observer.state_changed, "heat")
machine.heat()  >>> state is now 'LIQUID'
machine.heat()  >>> state is now 'GAS'
```

You could yest `before` instead and have a look how the output of `state_changed` changes. Furthermore, you can pass `source` or `destination` to narrow it further down:

```
machine.subscribe(observer.state_changed, "heat", source=State.LIQUID)
# ...
machine.heat()  >>> <nothing>
machine.heat()  >>> state is now 'GAS'
```

For unsubscribe you need to remember the filter settings or catch errors when `list.remove` tries to remove an element that is not in the callback array.

Comment: Your help is invaluable! The `self.get_state(state).on_enter.append(func)` line is what I was looking for.

Comment: What is the syntax to subscribe in the same way to specific transisions? Something like `self.get_transition(trigger, source, destination).before.append(func)`. I can't figure this out (quickly) from just reading the code... sorry for the hassle.

Comment: No worries, I added a section about transitions. You are almost right, `get_transitions` returns a list of transitions.

Comment: I am trying to also define an enum for triggers, but [getting an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68290388/how-to-define-enum-of-trigger-for-transitions-state-machine). Am I doing something wrong?