# How to define enum of Trigger for `transitions` state machine?

Tags: python, state-machine, pytransitions

As an unrelated followup to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68269299/913098), which isuses the following working code:

```
from transitions import Machine
from transitions import EventData
from typing import Callable
from enum import Enum, auto


class Observer:

    def state_changed(self, event_data: EventData):
        print(f"state is now '{event_data.state.name}'")


class State(Enum):
    SOLID = auto()
    LIQUID = auto()
    GAS = auto()


class SubscribableMachine(Machine):

    transitions = [
        {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': State.SOLID, 'dest': State.LIQUID},
        {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': State.LIQUID, 'dest': State.GAS},
        {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': State.GAS, 'dest': State.LIQUID},
        {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': State.LIQUID, 'dest': State.SOLID}
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(states=State, transitions=self.transitions,
                         initial=State.SOLID, send_event=True)

    def subscribe(self, func: Callable, state: State):
        self.get_state(state).on_enter.append(func)

    def unsubscribe(self, func: Callable, state: State):
        self.get_state(state).on_enter.remove(func)


machine = SubscribableMachine()
observer = Observer()
machine.subscribe(observer.state_changed, State.LIQUID)
machine.heat()  # >>> state is now 'LIQUID'
machine.heat()
assert machine.state == State.GAS
machine.unsubscribe(observer.state_changed, State.LIQUID)
machine.cool()  # no output
assert machine.state == State.LIQUID
```

I would like to have an enum for `Trigger` as well, just like I have one for `State`.

Alas, when I try

```
class Trigger(Enum):
    heat = auto()
    cool = auto()
```

and

```
transitions = [
    {'trigger': Trigger.heat, 'source': State.SOLID, 'dest': State.LIQUID},
    {'trigger': Trigger.heat, 'source': State.LIQUID, 'dest': State.GAS},
    {'trigger': Trigger.cool, 'source': State.GAS, 'dest': State.LIQUID},
    {'trigger': Trigger.cool, 'source': State.LIQUID, 'dest': State.SOLID}
]

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(states=State, transitions=self.transitions,
                     initial=State.SOLID, send_event=True)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/code/EPMD/Kodex/Algorithms/src/python/epmd/ablation_points/queries/dfgfdsg.py", line 42, in <module>
    machine = SubscribableMachine()
  File "C:/code/EPMD/Kodex/Algorithms/src/python/epmd/ablation_points/queries/dfgfdsg.py", line 33, in __init__
    initial=State.SOLID, send_event=True)
  File "C:\Code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\Lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py", line 589, in __init__
    self.add_model(model)
  File "C:\Code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\Lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py", line 607, in add_model
    self._add_trigger_to_model(trigger, mod)
  File "C:\Code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\Lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py", line 813, in _add_trigger_to_model
    self._checked_assignment(model, trigger, partial(self.events[trigger].trigger, model))
  File "C:\Code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\Lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py", line 807, in _checked_assignment
    if hasattr(model, name):
TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string
```

---

I can solve it by using `Enum`'s `.name`:

```
    transitions = [
        {'trigger': Trigger.heat.name, 'source': State.SOLID, 'dest': State.LIQUID},
        {'trigger': Trigger.heat.name, 'source': State.LIQUID, 'dest': State.GAS},
        {'trigger': Trigger.cool.name, 'source': State.GAS, 'dest': State.LIQUID},
        {'trigger': Trigger.cool.name, 'source': State.LIQUID, 'dest': State.SOLID}
    ]
```

But the asymmetry between `State` and `Trigger` bothers me.
Am I doing something wrong? Why does Enum work for `State` but not `Trigger`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [vish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68290769/1617563) already pointed out, there is no way to use Enums as triggers directly. Transitions binds trigger names as methods to models and thus requires triggers to be strings. However, `Machine` and all subclasses have been written with inheritance in mind. If you want to use Enums instead of classes and class attributes, you can just derive a suitable `EnumTransitionMachine` and get a unified interface:

```py
from transitions import Machine
from enum import Enum, auto


class State(Enum):
    A = auto()
    B = auto()
    C = auto()


class Transitions(Enum):
    GO = auto()
    PROCEED = auto()


class EnumTransitionMachine(Machine):

    def add_transition(self, trigger, *args, **kwargs):
        super().add_transition(trigger.name.lower() if hasattr(trigger, 'name') else trigger, *args, **kwargs)


transitions = [[Transitions.GO, State.A, State.B], [Transitions.PROCEED, State.B, State.C]]
m = EnumTransitionMachine(states=State, transitions=transitions, initial=State.A)
m.go()
assert m.state == State.B
m.proceed()
assert m.is_C()
```

FYI: there is also the possibility to use `Enums` with string values:

```py
class State(Enum):
    A = "A"
    B = "B"
    C = "C"


class Transitions(Enum):
    GO = "GO"
    PROCEED = "PROCEED"

# you could use the enum's value then instead:
    def add_transition(self, trigger, *args, **kwargs):
        super().add_transition(trigger.value.lower() if hasattr(trigger, 'value') else trigger, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error says it correctly:

`TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string`. If you go through enum documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), you will see what each of the functions return. You can override them and see if that works. Unless the code in `Machine` checks specifically for `Enum` and converts it to string, it would not work.

Simpler way to make it work, in a sort of way you want it is do following instead:

```py
class Trigger:
    HEAT = 'HEAT'
    COOL = 'COOL'
```